# Nginx reverse proxy issue in redirection without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, php, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I am running an nginx reverse proxy with apache as a backend server.
I have multiple applications running without any problems, but some php-js websites fails to redirect properly.
when I sent a request to *example.com/admin* it should redirects to *example.com/admin/* but instead I get a redirection to *example.com:**internal_port**/admin/*.

here is some useful information:

- Nginx configuration:

  ```
   server {
       server_name example.com;
       root /var/www/html/;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
       proxy_read_timeout 600s;

       }

        location ~ /\.ht {
               deny all;
       }

       listen 80;
   }
  ```
- apache configuration:

  ```
   <VirtualHost localhost:8080>

   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/
   ServerName localhost:8080
   LogLevel debug
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Http headers when requesting from backend server:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/admin -v

 GET /admin HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:8080
 User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
 Accept: */*

 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
 Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2022 17:59:37 GMT
 Location: http://localhost:8080/admin/
 Content-Length: 313
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://localhost:8080/admin/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
</body></html>
```

- http headers when requesting the virtual host:

```
$ curl example.com/admin -v


> GET /admin HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Thu, 07 Jul 2022 09:13:15 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 325
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://example.com:8080/admin/
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://example.com:8080/admin/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
```

Comment: Most probably your backend server is configured with the wrong base URL and is generating the redirect.

Comment: In your question you show response from the apache (`curl localhost:8080/admin -v`), not from the nginx (`curl localhost/admin -v`). The implicit `proxy_redirect default` directive should made nginx removing that port from the apache response; if it doesn't happen, most likely you have an explicit `proxy_redirect off` directive on the upper nginx configuration level.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I will edit my question and add a curl for what you have asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the following line to nginx config in the server block:

```
        rewrite /admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
```